# SQLite: How to get a match IN list AND another list

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables:

`Employee (id, name)`

`Department (id, name)`

`DepartmentLink (id, employeeId, departmentId)`

I'm trying to write a query that results in Employee IDs that have at least one departmentId in list A AND at least one departmentId in list B.

I tried this but it has no results:

```sql
SELECT
    Employee.id,
    DepartmentLink.departmentId
FROM DepartmentLink 
INNER JOIN Employee ON DepartmentLink.employeeId == Employee .id
WHERE DepartmentLink.departmentId IN (1,2,3)
AND DepartmentLink.departmentId IN (100)
```

The result should be an Employee (or just the ID) that is in department (1 or 2 or 3) AND in 100.

Is this possible in SQLite?

Comment: You could use `intersect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `INTERSECT`...

```
SELECT employeeId
FROM departmentLink
WHERE departmentId in (1, 2, 3)
INTERSECT
SELECT employeeId
FROM departmentLink
WHERE departmentId in (100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `exists` conditions:

```sql
SELECT e.id,
FROM   Employee e
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   DepartmentLink d1
               WHERE  d1.employeeId = e.id AND departmentId IN (1,2,3)) AND
       EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   DepartmentLink d2
               WHERE  d2.employeeId = e.id AND departmentId = 100)
```